# TeamCity integration tests

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I'd like to build such pipeline using TeamCity and Octopus Deploy:

TeamCity Part: Build -> Run Unit Tests -> Run Integration Tests -> Push to Octopus

Octopus: Deploy to Acceptance Server -> Deploy to production

When I need run integration tests on TeamCity agent I have to set up test database connection string in configuration file + parameters.

Then on octopus side I have to change connection string again for every server.

As a result I have to change configuration in different places. What is not comfortable... Is there a way to keep configuration transformations in one place, something like this: Build -> Run Unit Tests -> Push to octopus -> Change configuration for tests -> Push to Team City -> Run Integration Tests -> Push to Octopus -> ...

Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to run your tests as part of the build to make sure your project works before deploying, why do you want to run 1 set of tests, push to Octopus, then run another set, then push again? Wouldn't it make more sense to follow the 1st flow you described & run all tests in TeamCity, then deploy?

Comment: Also, your question on how to deal with configurations is a bit unclear, but you can store connection strings in files or environmental variables locally for each machine in a consistent spot, then have your configuration code always look at that location and use whatever's there to connect to the db. Then you won't have to make any changes per machine.